# C++ multiple classes inheriting from a base class causing issues

Tags: c++, linux, oop

so, i have basically designed a "Hello, World!" OOP with c++.
I have 2 classes, chicken and dog that inherit from public animal.
In int main, when i create an instance of each, i get error messages that claims i have created multiple instances of the class Animal.

`Animal.h`

```
#ifndef ANIMAL
class Animal
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  public:
    void setPosition(int newX, int newY, int newZ);
    void setX(int newX);
    void setY(int newY);
    void setZ(int newZ);
    int getPosition();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getZ();
};
#endif
```

`Chicken.h`

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#include "../animal.h"
#endif
class Chicken : public Animal
{
  int id;
  bool isClucking;
  bool isEnraged;
  public:
    void setID(int newID);
    void setClucking(bool yn);
    void setEnraged(bool yn);
    int getID();
    bool getClucking();
    bool getEnraged();
};
```

`Dog.h`

```
#include "../animal.h"
class Dog : public Animal
{
  int id;
  public:
    void setID(int newID);
    int getID();
};
```

Code here: [Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt0xpdzgysxoixu/Code.zip)

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Rather than linking to the complete code, please edit your question to include a [short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, please post the exact error messages from your compiler - and the name and version of your compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the animal.h defined as

```
#ifndef ANIMAL
class Animal
{
```

should be

```
#ifndef ANIMAL
#define ANIMAL
class Animal
{
```

so that `animal.h` is not included multiple times.

Also for consistency, have all your headers have a [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). So dog and chicken need it.

---

Unless you really need it

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#include "../animal.h"
#endif
```

should simply be

```
#include "../animal.h"
```

because the former construct requires the `define` exactly match which in your cause is already not matching. `animal.h` defines `ANIMAL` or at least tries to but where you include is you are checking for `ANIMAL_H`

Comment: I would encourage the use of `#pragma once` BTW ;)